# Como acceder a un ítem (key) especifico de un diccionario en Django Template - Python

Tags: python, django

Tengo este diccionario:  periodo = {'month':10, 'month_name':'Octubre', 'year': 2020}

quiero acceder solamente al  month_name y year en django template. y lo mismo en python

Comment: En python: `periodo["month_name"]`. En Django Template: `{{periodo.month_name}}`

Comment: Me sirvió, gracias